# Build error when running `npx react-native run-windows`

Tags: react-native-windows

After run npx `npx react-native run-windows` in my react native windows project directory, I got error

`× Building Solution: D:\Code\Visual Studio\IDE\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5):...`

`× Build failed with message Building Solution returned error code 1. Check your build configuration.`

I checked development dependencies
`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force;`
and
`iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://aka.ms/rnw-deps.ps1')`, it's good

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdYUZ.jpg)